# Como sumar elementos de un functor en prolog

Tags: prolog

Yo tengo la fecha de cuando va a ser la fiesta dada en forma de functor. Ahora yo de esa fecha tengo que se relaciona con el nombre de un tipo de comida el cual este tipo de comida es otro functor. Al obtener la fecha, yo quiero gestionar de ese tipo de comida, a base del nombre de una comida perteneciente a este functor, la cantidad para la que alcanza a comer (cantidad de personas que pueden comer). El problema esta en que no puedo gestionar la cantidades distintas y sumarlas.

```
//      functor( Comida, Ingredientes, Cantidad Personas que pueden comer)
comida(sandwich(tripleDeMiga, [jamon, queso, huevoDuro], 1)).
comida(snacks(papasFritas, lays, 2)).

//      functor( Comida, Cantidad Personas que pueden comer)
comida(plato(pizzaMuzzarella, 4)).

comidaEnFiesta(fecha(10,3,2018), pizzaMuzzarela).
comidaEnFiesta(fecha(10,3,2018), papasFritas).


fiestaBajon(Fecha):- 
    comidaEnFiesta(Fecha, Comida),
    findall(Cantidad, alcanzaPara(Comida, Cantidad), listaCantidades),
    sum(listaCantidades, Total),
    Total < 4.

alcanzaPara(Comida, Cantidad):- comida(sandwich(Comida, _, Cantidad)).
alcanzaPara(Comida, Cantidad):- comida(plato(Comida, Cantidad)).
alcanzaPara(Comida, Cantidad):- comida(snacks(Comida, _, Cantidad)).
```

De esta forma me da error, o sea, si me devuelve un numero pero no el que necesito. Solo devuelve la cantidad de la ultima comida, pero no me suma la cantidad de todas las comidas.